# Set symbol server in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols, visual-studio-mac, symbol-server

Where is the corresponding setting for setting the symbol server
in VS for Mac?
 I can't find it, is this feature *überhaupt* available?

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not currently support symbol servers. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/32936734-symbol-server-support